# how to retrieve all row selected checkboxes of a table as list in Jquery?

Tags: jquery-ui

how to retrieve all row selected checkboxes of a table as list and add these elements to another table in Jquery?

many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the [jQuery.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) function

```
$('#row input:checked').each(function(){
  // Do your adding to the other table inhere for each checkbox :) 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to say specifically without your markup but:

```
var checked = $(':checked');
```

will get you all the checked inputs. if you want the values in an array you could do:

```
var values = $(':checked').map(function(ele,idx){
  return $(ele).val();
});
```

or if you want the field names:

```
var values = $(':checked').map(function(ele,idx){
  return $(ele).attr('name');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks!
I've got it :-)!
I did it like this:

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').each(function(){          
            if ($(this).is(':checked')) {                   
                    var obj_id = $('#tbodyMapNotUsed :checked').parents("tr");  
                    if( $('#tbodyMap').length > 0){
                    $(obj_id).clone(true).insertAfter('#tableMap tbody>tr:first');
                }
                else{
                    $('#tableMap').append($('<tbody id="tbodyMap"><tr></tr>'));
                    $(obj_id).clone(true).insertAfter('#tableMap tbody>tr:first');
                    $('#tableMap').append($('</tbody>'));
                }
                    $(obj_id).clone(true).insertAfter('#tableMapAll tbody>tr:first');
                    $(obj_id).remove();
            }

    });
```